# Cannot Stat Error When Copying From Android Phone to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: bash, android, mtp

I am trying to move a video file from my phone to my harddrive via a script and am running into trouble with permissions. I am using the following command:

```
sudo cp "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=[usb:003,008]/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20140520_142150.mp4" ./
```

And when I try that I get the error:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=[usb:003,008]/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20140520_142150.mp4’: Permission denied
```

I'm not sure what to make of a permission denied error when using sudo. Any tips on getting this to work?

Comment: Escape the brackets in the host name  `host=\[usb:003,008\]`

Comment: The resulting output is the same. I also tried `sudo cp /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A003%2C012%5D/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20140520_142150.mp4 ./` using tab to build the filename and again, permission denied.

Comment: Look here,it might help http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/what-does-cp-cannot-stat-mean-640617/